# SSL and web security: request resubmission

Tags: security, ssl

Say I am sending a HTTPS request to a REST API. The request triggers a payment.

Can somebody in the middle just capture the request, guess it is a payment request and re-submitted to the API so that to trigger that payment twice?

That's regardless the communication is encrypted with SSL and the server and client use temporary authentication tokens rather than passwords, right?

I understand the scope of this question is very wide and general - general answers would be therefore welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you have described is called a "replay attack" and TLS/SSL is designed in general to defeat them.

From the [TLS RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346#appendix-F.2):

> To prevent message replay or modification attacks, the MAC is computed from the MAC secret, the sequence number, the message length, the message contents, and two fixed character strings.